# Removing Default Search Box and "Home / Edit" link in Oslo

Tags: 2013, search-box

I want these things done for a single subsite. I needed to do some special things with searching on the site that involved basically breaking the default, built-in search box. But it still shows up. What's the simplest way of getting this box to not load (on the main page and in all the document libraries for this subsite).

Picture of search box in question: https://mega.co.nz/#!SB1jWDgA!77xHRbs9H10Cp4N9htOvH4ZGJ9v8L6gBvwB5FzlzJ7s Include file key

This is also the only site I'm aware of using the Oslo template. I'd like "Home" gone. Anyone know of an easy way to accomplish this? Thanks.

Picture of "home": https://mega.co.nz/#!7JMCxRiZ!6I__zvkAlDIkxFfx_1Z9A4iW_eL89i8KJ2kT-3HuZEQ

Thanks.

Comment: Both the links are invalid.

Comment: Are you using a separate sub site or the same one as the rest of your site collection? If you're using the same one you'll have to put jQuery on each page otherwise you can just edit the master page.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to remove the default search box, you may try hiding this search box element.

```
#SearchBox {
    display:none;
}
```

For Home/Edit also you can identify the elements and then do the same or edit the masterpage for removing the elements.

Comment: Agreed. CSS is the easiest way to remove the search bar - and it really doesn't talemuch to implement :)